# How do I copy a file from a deployed web site to a local directory using MS Web Deploy (msdeploy.exe)?

Tags: msdeploy

I already came up with a command that deploys the site to the target server and it works great. In case it is important in this context, here it is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
  -source:package='HelloWorld.Mvc3UI\obj\Debug\Package\HelloWorld.Mvc3UI.zip' 
  -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://10.225.0.30:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=HelloWorld',username='<MyUserName>',password='<MyPassword>',authType='basic',includeAcls='false'
  -allowUntrusted 
  -verb:sync 
  -disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
  -disableLink:ContentExtension 
  -disableLink:CertificateExtension 
  -setParamFile:"HelloWorld.Mvc3UI\obj\Debug\Package\HelloWorld.Mvc3UI.SetParameters.xml" 
  -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='HelloWorld' 
  -setParam:name='HelloWorld-Web.config Connection String',value='SERVER=10.225.0.25;DATABASE=HelloWorld;UID=sa;PWD=<MyPassword>;'
```

Now that the site is on the server, I want to be able to retrieve the \bin\HelloWorld.Database.dll file and copy it to a local directory using msdeploy.exe.

I am guessing that I have to use the package provider on the remote server (since it is what was used to deploy the site) and use the dirPath or filePath provider on the local machine. However, I am having trouble working out the exact syntax to make it work.

**Background**

I need the HelloWorld.Database.dll file that is already in production so it can be used to downgrade the database in an application rollback scenario. This file uses the [Fluent Migrator Framework](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki) to migrate the database changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
  -source:filePath='C:\inetpub\sites\HelloWorld\bin\HelloWorld.Database.dll',ComputerName='https://10.225.0.30:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=HelloWorld',username='<MyUserName>',password='<MyPassword>',authType='basic',includeAcls='false' 
  -dest:filePath='F:\HelloWorldProject\HelloWorld.Database.dll' 
  -allowUntrusted 
  -verb:sync
```

However I would much prefer if there were a way to do this without having to specify the entire remote path because it might vary from one environment to the next. I tried and apparently it isn't supported.